# Math Formula for a Recursive Relation of any K-Ary Tree

Tags: recursion, trees

First hand, my apologies if the question has already been repeated before.

Currently, I'm trying to figure out what exactly the formula for any recursive k-ary tree would look like at any depth for a program I'm writing on.

So far, I know this formula is great for a 2-ary tree:

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2)

[ https://qph.cf2.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-40df14204e47a8e36be14e29994b2a70 ] (I can't post images yet but this link will show you what the formula above is able to do..)
```

However, I'm trying to see if there is a formula that works with ANY K-ary tree. I'm trying to come up with a program where the user decides what *k* will be and how much total depth will it contain.

For example, if a k-ary tree has *k = 5* and total depth *d = 2* then mathematically, it will know for parent node 5 the child nodes are: 25, 26, 27, 28, 29 and 30.

(I know this isn't the coding section of Stack Exchange but for now I'm just trying to find a formula).

Thank you!

Comment: What are you trying to count?

Comment: @DanielV My apologies, I don't understand your question.

I'm looking for a recurrence regression formula that can work with any k and depth value. I don't know exactly where to look for one that fits this description...

Comment: A tree is not a number.

Comment: @DanielV No, as in a formula that's able to determine what the NEXT nodes would be.

For example, for the formula I listed above, it can tell what the next set of child nodes are (for node 1, it knows the next child nodes are 3 and 4) by utilizing mathematics.

Comment: There's more than one way to label a tree with numbers. Can you clarify what the trees you're interested in look like and explain what the values of your desired function represent?

Comment: @Karl I'm interested in creating extremely large type of trees that are able to exceed pass a large amount of depth regardless of how wide and how many perfect nodes per parent node (based on k) the tree contains.

Basically each node in the tree is labeled by a numeric value going up in 1 (node 5 is labeled as node 5 and etc...) The only values I desire for my function to contain are k-ary and depth for any individual to place into the function to figure out what the next set of nodes are based on recurrence regression...

Comment: So you have a [perfect $k$-ary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-ary_tree) and your nodes are numbered in [breadth first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) order? And you want a function $f(k, n)$ that gives you the label of the first node on the $n$th level? Or the label of the first child of the $n$th node?

Comment: If your numbering starts at $1$, then the children of node $n$ are nodes $k(n-1)+1$ through $kn$.

Comment: But it's not clear how your $T(n)$ recurrence or the linked image is relevant.